# Ionic iOS build - Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm not sure what the issue is.  When I build for Android it works fine but when I try to emulate the iOS app, it throws this error and just shows a blank page or our splash page. Error message is Thread 1: signal SIGABRT.  Thanks.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

2015-12-22 12:59:58.829 Wheres My Concrete[10525:69572] DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///Users/cos/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CA2D24F6-2002-40EF-BCBE-FEDFC4B6B72D/data/Containers/Data/Application/F7880FBA-7728-45FB-B247-88B047904CEE/Library/Cookies/com.wheresmyconcrete.binarycookies
2015-12-22 12:59:59.103 Wheres My Concrete[10525:69572] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'

Comment: Whenever the app crashed it shows only this page. Can you please provide line of codes where it occur. please find by breakpoints

Comment: There will be some error message in the Xcode console, check that and include it along with the question. And the above mentioned code is not responsible for those crash, crash is happening somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root view controller you are loading has an outlet to nothing. The answer is in the error

```
 reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
```

This usually is because in your interface file, xib or storyboard, you have an outlet set but you may have deleted the object it was pointing to.
In xcode interface builder, click the initial view controller and have a look at the right to the outlets.

[image]

See how my outlets have all got connections(ignoring the searchDisplayController), yours need to also. 
If you are really clutching at straws, then you could remove all outlets and see if it runs, if it does then do a process of elimination by adding one outlet at a time.

Comment: hey i am facing same problem. please help me.

Comment: did you follow what i said? stacktrace?

Comment: hey thank for the replay i am new in ionic and specially in for iOS xcode. i will get this error when i install Firebase Cloud Messaging Cordova plugin for push notification(https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm). and if i will uninstall this plugin my ionic app working fine if you have any idea plz suggest me.

Comment: You should ask that in a seperate stack overflow question. Looks totally unrellevant to the original question

Comment: Thanks, I'm new at Xcode project, so I didn't know how to see stack trace. I finally got the reason why SIGABRT happened. Thanks!